# Pass the Debugging from Assemby/NuGet Package, OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, oxyplot

Good afternoon,

I had to use a graph for my project so i downloaded two NuGet `Oxyplot.Core` `Oxyplot.Wpf`.

Which is great but every time I do `F11` and try to debug through my code  it always ask me where is oxyplot.cs.

So following on internet did some setting and visual studio downloaded the file and now rather than showing the error about where is the oxyplot.cs.

Is it opens it and i have to go though all the code of oxyplot which i dont wanted to. All i wanted was to pass the debugger when comes anything related to the Oxyplot.

I tried to keep `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`, but since the file is readonly i cannot modify it.

I have looked over stack for answer, but still now i cannot pass my debugger and just check my code.

Is there any solution you guys can suggest please. I saw some solution but has not worked for me yet. Following in my setting for debugging settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable 'Managed Compatibility Mode'. This option forces VS to use old debugger.